# Can we have a Stack Overflow-like site for database related questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, database

There are many questions already on Meta Stack Overflow regarding the database schema, but here is another, that I don't think is a duplicate, so please read on.

Can we have Stack Overflow for Database related Questions ?

Comment: (Can you please use a question mark rather than an exclamation mark when asking questions? Thanks!)

Comment: The question seems more clear than the explanation -- on Meta Stack Overflow, I doubt -- database schema, what does it mean here

Comment: Stack Exchange's [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) is the place to propose your site ideas. You can read more about that process here: [area51.stackexchange.com/faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). I am going to close this as off topic for *this* site.

Answer (score 6):

There already [is one.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators)

Comment: oh! thanks a lot ! I wasn't aware about it !

Comment: Well we have to wait some more days, until the beta starts

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql~ - 59,809 questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database~ - 18,691 questions.

Comment: Further 3298 on http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql~  and 189 on http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql~ .

Comment: @bernd_k Ah, was trying to find how to pattern-match!

Comment: I found it by adding sql* to interesting tags. I use it to filter newest questions